# Gulp function with value "sass('floder1')"

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I am trying to use same gulpfile.js for multiple projects. Let's say I want to use same `sass()` function for two different project. I have tried passing value like javascript `sass(x){.... .src(x+"/src/style/scss/*.scss")}`. But it didnt work. Is there any example of using same gulpfile.js for multiple projects?

```
function css(x) {
  return gulp
    .src(x+"/src/style/scss/*.scss")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: "expanded"
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(x+"/src/style/css"))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
      compatibility: 'ie8'
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(x+'/src/min/css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(x+'/dist/css'));
}

function watch(x){
   gulp.watch(x+'/src/style/scss/**', css(x));
   gulp.watch(x+'/src/js/**', js(x));
   gulp.watch(x+'/dist/**', deploy(x));
}
```

running in command like: `gulp watch("folder1")`

it doesnt do anything. or, it is not watching any folder & running any task.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) package for that

In your gulpfile

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
```

**change function to**

And you can Access variable using `argv[x]` like that

```
function watch(){
   console.log('It works!!' +argv['x']);
   gulp.watch(argv['x']+'/src/style/scss/**', css(argv['x']));
   gulp.watch(argv['x']+'/src/js/**', js(argv['x']));
   gulp.watch(argv['x']+'/dist/**', deploy(argv['x']));
}
```

in your command line

```
$ gulp watch --x=folder1
```

Hope this will helps...!